# Can I alert all my elements?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to send all the elements in my document to the alert function?
If so, how can I do that?

Here is an example document. I want to print all of the elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  h3 { margin: 0; }
  div,span,p {
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>DIV</div>

  <span>SPAN</span>
  <p>P <button>Button</button></p>
<script>var elementCount = $("*").css("border","3px solid red").length;
$("body").prepend("<h3>" + elementCount + " elements found</h3>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not an answer (per se), but if you're debugging, use `console.log()` in Firebug or Chrome Console.

Comment: What is the expected output from the above code and what do you get currently?

Comment: Luckily the answer is dirt-simple. I suppose someone should copyedit the question though.

Comment: i don't like the way you spelled possible

Comment: "I want to print all of the elements."
In this case: `alert(document.doctype+'\n'+document.documentElement.outerHTML);`

Comment: @Teemu the doctype is a node, but not an element. Also if there is no doctype this will end up as the string "null", which will make for broken XML.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do it like this:

```
alert(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
```